# Opentext in VBA when Local information is different

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm creating a Macro that involves opening 2 or 3 `.csv` files and copying them into sheet.

The files looks like this (semicolon separated, and decimal = comma):

```
A;B;AT;211,00;2
```

I've solved that by using:

```
Workbooks.OpenText filepath, DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True, local:=True
Windows(filename).Actvate
df = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

And then leaving `df`where I want in my worksheet. This works fine when working on my local computer but the problem comes when i want to run this macro in the server. Where it opens the file incorrectly (It separates the columns by the `,` not by the `;` like in local.

This macro is going to be run by local, server, and different users so I would like to know:

- Why does this happen?
- How can I make it dynamic?

**[Edit]**  With the help of the answer, i'm trying these **without success**:

```
If Application.DecimalSeparator = "." Then
   Workbooks.OpenText filepath, DataType:=xlDelimited, semicolon:=True
ElseIf Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then
   Workbooks.OpenText filepath, DataType:=xlDelimited, comma:=True, local:=True
End If
```

**[Edit 2]**

This works as a solution, but it's really slow:

```
Open filepath For Input As #1
row_num = 1
Do Until EOF(1)
 Input #1, varlist, Line_FromFile
 Line_Items = Split(Line_FromFile, ";")
 nele = UBound(Line_Items, 1)
 Range(rango.Offset(row_num, 0), rango.Offset(row_num, nele)) = Line_Items
 row_num = row_num + 1
Loop
Close #1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply check what the decimal separator is for that system and then decide how you will use the `.OpenText`

```
If Application.DecimalSeparator = "." Then

ElseIf Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then

End If
```

If the above doesn't work then use this alternative

```
If Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) = "." Then

ElseIf Application.International(xlDecimalSeparator) = "," Then

End If
```

Comment: The `if application.decimalseparator` is working, but I still don't get to use the right `opentext` parameters

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code that you are using with `Application.DecimalSeparator`

Comment: Yeah, sure, I'm afraid I will have to use another method like the `open file for....`

Answer (score -1):

```
xlsObj=CreateObject("Excel.Application");
xlsObj.Visible = 0;
xlsObj.ScreenUpdating = 0;
xlsObj.EnableEvents = 0;
xlsObj.DisplayAlerts = 0; 
xlsObj.DecimalSeparator = ".";
xlsObj.ThousandsSeparator = "";
xlsObj.UseSystemSeparators = 0;
xlsOpenFile = xlsObj.Workbooks.Open(strFileName,0,1);
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question.